# "Non-void function should return a value" when capturing Self in Swift 4.2 guard statement in closure in function

Tags: swift, rx-swift, self

How can we use the Swift 4.2 style of capturing self in closures in functions that returns a type?

For example:

```
func checkEmailExists(_ email: String) -> Observable<Bool> {
    return Observable.create { [weak self] observer in
        guard let self = self else { return }
        self.callAPI()
    }
}
```

This generates an error `Non-void function should return a value` but also it should not `return false` as this will influence the outcome of the function call.

EDIT: Another example, throws `Non-void function should return a value`

```
func loginWithCredentials() -> Observable<User> {
    return Observable.create { [weak self] observer in
        guard let self = self else { return }

        let decoder = JSONDecoder()
        let json = ["id": 1, "name": "John Doe", "email": "john@doe.com"] as [String: Any]

        do {
            let user = try decoder.decode(User.self, from: json.jsonData()!)
            observer.onNext(user) // Simulation of successful user authentication.
        } catch {
            print("error")
        }

        return Disposables.create()
    }
}
```

Comment: If it can't be `false` also then you should make the value as an `Optional` and return `nil`

Comment: According to the signature of the method  you have to return an `Observable<Bool>` value in the `else` clause as well as `callAPI()` must return an `Observable<Bool>` value.

Comment: This doesn't look like a correct use of `Observables.create()`. When is `observer.on()` called? What do you believe this code is doing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to return a disposable in any case.

```
func checkEmailExists(_ email: String) -> Observable<Bool> {
    return Observable.create { [weak self] observer in
        guard let self = self else { return Disposables.create() }
        // and so on...
        return Disposables.create { /* cancelation code */ }
    }
}
```

This feels very wrong though. Your function `callAPI()` should *itself* be returning an Observable of some sort which would make this function pointless.

Comment: The initial code was just too simplified, sorry. I've added another example. Thanks for the answer!

Comment: The answer is the same. The closure you pass into create is a non-void function, you have to return a Disposable. You aren't doing that which is why you are getting the error.

Answer (score -3):

Try make return type as *optional* and return `nil` if there is no *self*

**OR**

You can avoid this `guard` statement by calling your method with `?` sign like:

```
self?.callAPI()
```

Comment: This is not recommended. Since Swift 4.2 the `guard let self = self else { return }` is the recommended approach.

Comment: @Blackbeard is that documented?